# Getting python homework dictionary program to save and exit properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a homework problem. Have almost all of the code working but for some reason cant seem to get my program to save and exit properly. 
here is the prompt given.

> You should create a program that manages a tab-separated text file containing employees travel expenses. There are 4 and only 4 employees who travel for the company: alice, bob, carl, and diane. Each record in the data file will contain an employee name, a destination city, miles traveled, and gallons used.
>
> For full credit:
>
> - Your program should properly read and store the given data to and from the tab-separated data file. That is, I should be able to use your program with my data file without error.
> - When the data is read into your program it should be organized as a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is a row in the file, using these dictionary keys: name, city, miles, gallons.
> - You need to add functionality to display the user's name, total miles traveled, total gallons used, average mpg, and the expense of the total miles at 75 cents per mile. This should work for any of the 4 proper user names you enter.
> - You do not need to do any data validation unless just want to.
> - If and only if your program runs exactly like it should, I will add a 10 point bonus if, rather than using concatenation, you properly use the python CSV module to read and write the data to and from the file, converting the tab-separated data to a dictionary and vice versa.
> - You need to use the base code provided by the lecture notes, more or less. All 4 menu options should work.
> - Use formatting to have everything line up in neat columns for display option 1.

My problem is that I cannot get the 4th option "Save and exit" to function properly.

```
def read_file(travels):
    salesperson_list = []
    with open("travels.txt", 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            line = line.strip().split('\t')
            d = {}
            d['name'] = line[0]
            d['city'] = line[1]
            d['miles'] = eval(line[2])
            d['gallons'] = eval(line[3])
            salesperson_list.append(d)
    return salesperson_list


def display_all_data(data):
    print('{0:<8}{1:<15}{2:<8}{3:<8}'.format('Name', 'City', 'Miles', 'Gallons'))
    for row in data:
        print('{0:<8}{1:<15}{2:^8}{3:^8}'.format(row.get('name'), row.get('city'), \
                                                 row.get('miles'), row.get('gallons')))


def calculate_user_data(data):
    name = input('Enter user name: ').lower()
    total_miles = sum([row.get('miles') for row in data if row.get('name') == name])
    total_gallons = sum([row.get('gallons') for row in data if row.get('name') == name])
    cities = [row.get('city') for row in data if row.get('name') == name]
    mpg = total_miles/total_gallons
    owed = mpg*0.75
    print('Total miles travelled: {0}'.format(total_miles))
    print('Total gallons used: {0}'.format(total_gallons))
    print('mpg = ',mpg)
    print('expense = $', owed, 'at 75 cents per mile')


def add_a_trip(data):
    name = input('Input name: ').lower()
    city = input('Input city travelled: ').lower()
    miles = eval(input('Enter miles travelled: '))
    gallons = eval(input('Enter gallons used: '))
    d = {}
    d['name'] = name
    d['city'] = city
    d['miles'] = miles
    d['gallons'] = gallons
    data.append(d)
    print('Data added successfully')


def save_And_exit(data):
    with open('F:\\travels.txt','w') as outfile:
        for row in data:
            outfile.write(row.get('name')+'\t'+row.get('city')+'\t'+\
                      str(row.get('miles'))+'\t'+str(row.get('gallons'))+'\n')
    print('Saved to file')

def menu(salesperson_list):

    print('Menu options. Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4')
    print('[1] Display all trip data')
    print('[2] Calculate user data')
    print('[3] Add a trip')
    print('[4] Save an exit')
    while True:
        choice = input('Enter choice --> ')
        if choice == '1':
            display_all_data(salesperson_list)
        elif choice == '2':
            calculate_user_data(salesperson_list)
        elif choice == '3':
            add_a_trip(salesperson_list)
        elif choice == '4':
            save_And_exit(salesperson_list)
            print('Bye')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid selection')


def main():
    salesperson_list = read_file('F:\\travels.txt')
    menu(salesperson_list)
main()
```

I just need my program to save and exit properly with no global variables

Comment: what error is it giving?

Comment: Just a hunch, but it looks like you're writing this on Windows. Sometimes, it will protect the root of a drive, "F:\" for example, from non-admins. Try changing the paths from `F:\\travels.txt` to `travels.txt` (and then it'll read/write in your current directory). It's hard to say much else without detail about your error.

Comment: That did it. Wow. this has been driving me nuts and the solution was so simple. Thanks!